# Rope for tying young trees into position (strong, non-stretch, weather resistant, no fray, 1/8-inch thick)

Tags: equipment

I often tie young trees or branches into position. For example, if a 1-2 inch diameter tree is crooked, I'll hammer a 2x2 stake into the ground, and tie the tree to the stake so that the tree grows straight.

1. It takes quite a bit of force to manipulate a tree like that. So the rope needs to be strong and not stretch.
2. I don't want the rope to fray at the ends when I cut it. Frayed ends are awkward to thread through loops and tie with.

   - For example, I tried [threaded braided nylon rope (1/8 of an inch)](https://www.thepackagingcompany.com/solid-braided-nylon-rope-1-8-black.html), but the strands unravel when cut which is a nuisance.
3. The rope needs to be weather resistant. I don't want it to break down due to sun or moisture. I want it to stay in place for a few years.
4. The rope thickness should be at least 1/8 inch thick so that it doesn't cut into the tree bark much.

What kind of rope matches that criteria?

---

I'm not looking for a critique of my tree-tying method. I'm aware that rope can damage trees over time. I've been using this method for 15 years and am happy with it -- using various kinds of rope that meet *some* of the criteria above. I have a technique where I make a loop at the end of the rope and thread the other end of the rope through it -- making a loose loop around the tree. So it doesn't constrict the tree much or cause disease. And I am diligent about removing the rope after a few years.

Comment: Odd. I see a contradiction in this post: "It takes quite a bit of force to manipulate a tree like that. So the rope needs to be strong and not stretch." and "I have a technique where I make a loop at the end of the rope and thread the other end of the rope through it -- making a loose loop around the tree."  So - do you want a rope that can force a tree into straightness or one that allows the tree to move but prevents it from bending too much in high winds? Have you tried threading the rope through a piece of an old hose to protect the trunk?

Answer (score 1):

Steel cable, galvanized or stainless. I used plain steel and the brown color was good for me. Steel can be attached with lag screws, nut and bolt, etc, so no problem protecting the bark from pressure . Bark will grow over metal fasteners and hide them in a couple years.

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting with a few kinds of rope, I've found 550 paracord works well (like [this](https://ropeshop.ca/shop/all/550-commercial-paracord/)).

1. Is very strong and doesn't stretch.
2. It doesn't fray much.
3. It doesn't break down in the sun, even after a few years. And of course, it doesn't rot when wet.
4. It's thick enough so that it doesn't cut into the tree bark. But isn't so thick that it is awkward to tie with. And it isn't overly slippery like nylon rope (nylon rope knots sometimes slip/loosen over time).

The downside is that paracord is expensive. But it can be purchased in bulk, making the price manageable.

Comment: For 2., a flame will weld the end shut and eliminate fraying.